# In jQuery UI calendar making different background in first and last child of highlighted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

This is quite complex, at least it is for me.

What I have now is jQuery UI calendar and I made it so that user in backend can choose specific dates.
This works well and it creates this:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uqn0nR3MdGdF9iQXY5LVdNYlU/view?usp=drivesdk

But is not enough. I need to go step further and to create calendar like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1uqn0nR3MdGMkttc1JEbzB3eWM/view?usp=drivesdk

So when user selects any accommodation is not available from 1st December to 21 December, 1st and 21st should have this half-red-half-green background.

Currently only 1 class is created on this my calendar ( for unavailable dates ) `.ui-state-highlight`, I was trying to separate all closed parts as array and with jquery or css append different backgorund on first and last child of that array but had no luck...

So if on these 3 calendars that are shown are closed next dates:
1-21 december
27dec-02January
23-25January

Currently all these dates have class `ui-state-highlight` and they are all red.
What I need is that 1st, 21st, 27th december and 02,23,25january have this red-green background.

Any ideas?

Below is example of HTML code that is generated in calendar.

```html
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><span title="Monday">Mo</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">Tu</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">We</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">Th</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><span title="Friday">Fr</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Sa</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">1</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">2</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">3</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">4</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">6</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">7</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">8</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">9</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">10</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">11</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">12</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">13</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">14</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight"><span class="ui-state-default">15</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight"><span class="ui-state-default">16</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight"><span class="ui-state-default">17</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight"><span class="ui-state-default">18</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight"><span class="ui-state-default">19</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">20</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">21</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">22</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">23</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">24</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">25</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">26</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">27</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">28</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">29</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">30</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled "><span class="ui-state-default">31</span>
      </td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add some code samples. It's kinda hard to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: I added some HTML that is generated as OUTPUT, this part with classes .ui-highlight is in css styles as background:red so we see it red(not available in frontend) , now I need first and last date from that 'red' row to be half-red-half-green background ( or just put background-color:yellow for these two )... I suppose some JS must be written and css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom function that identifies your days of interest and apply a custom CSS class using the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) method.

For the background of the days that are red/green, you can use the [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) function along with the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property.

Here´s a quick example:

```js
var START_DATE = new Date('11/8/2015');

var END_DATE = new Date('11/22/2015');

var opts = {
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {

    var ts = date.getTime();

    if (ts === START_DATE.getTime()) {
      return [true, 'custom-start', null];
    } else if (ts > START_DATE.getTime() && ts < END_DATE.getTime()) {
      return [true, 'custom-between', null];
    } else if (ts === END_DATE.getTime()) {
      return [true, 'custom-end', null];
    } else {
      return [true, '', ''];
    }

  }
};

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker(opts);
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
  background: #c4ffc2;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .custom-start .ui-state-default {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #c4ffc2 0%, #c4ffc2 50%, #ffbfc9 51%, #ffbfc9 100%);
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .custom-between .ui-state-default {
  background: #ffbfc9;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar .custom-end .ui-state-default {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ffbfc9 0%, #ffbfc9 50%, #c4ffc2 51%, #c4ffc2 100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked, I mean we had to do some changes and so, but main idea is used from Your answer. Thanks!